# Binary Search Tree (BST) Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, binary-search-tree

This is the first Time implementing a Binary Search Tree, based on how it works from the visualgo website. I made this algorithm purely based on what I saw, and the remove method was quite challenging. How can I improve the speed/efficiency and make the code look better?

Methods:

- Inorder: basically an inorder traversal through the BST Ex: 1 3 4 6 19 25
- Insert: inserts a node with a certain value
- lookup: returns the value if it exists in the BST else returns None
- getMin: returns the min value in the specified node
- remove: removes a value, and if current_node is not specified then, it starts from the root node, a bit recursive, even though I wanted to implement a way without recursion, but I couldn't see it working without it in any way.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def inorder(self, current_node):
        if current_node:  
            self.inorder(current_node.left)
            print(current_node.value, end=' ')
            self.inorder(current_node.right)

    def insert(self, value):
        NewNode = Node(value) 
        current_node = self.root
        if current_node is None:
            self.root = NewNode
        else:
            while True:
                if value < current_node.value:
                    #Left
                    if not current_node.left:
                        current_node.left = NewNode
                        return self
                    current_node = current_node.left
                else:
                    if not current_node.right:
                        current_node.right = NewNode
                        return self
                    current_node = current_node.right

    def lookup(self, value):
        current_node = self.root
        if current_node is None:
            return None
        while current_node:
            current_value = current_node.value
            if value < current_value:
                current_node = current_node.left
            elif value > current_value:
                current_node = current_node.right
            else:
                return current_node

    def getMin(self, current_node):
        while current_node.left is not None:
            current_node = current_node.left
        return current_node.value

    def remove(self, value, current_node=False):
        if not current_node:
            current_node = self.root

        if not current_node: # if the root is None
            return None

        parent_node = None
        while current_node:
            current_value = current_node.value
            if value < current_value:   
                parent_node = current_node
                current_node = current_node.left
            elif value > current_value:
                parent_node = current_node
                current_node = current_node.right
            else:
                # No Child
                if not current_node.left and not current_node.right:
                    if parent_node is None:
                        self.root = None
                    elif current_node == parent_node.left:
                        parent_node.left = None
                    else:
                        parent_node.right = None

                # One Child
                elif current_node.right and not current_node.left:
                    if parent_node is None:
                        self.root = current_node.right
                    elif current_node == parent_node.left:
                        parent_node.left = current_node.right
                    else:
                        parent_node.right = current_node.right

                elif current_node.left and not current_node.right:
                    if parent_node is None:
                        self.root = current_node.left
                    elif current_node == parent_node.left:
                        parent_node.left = current_node.left
                    else:
                        parent_node.right = current_node.left

                # Two Child
                else:
                    in_order_successor = self.getMin(current_node.right)

                    self.remove(in_order_successor, current_node)
                    if parent_node is None:
                        self.root.value = in_order_successor
                    elif current_node == parent_node.left:
                        parent_node.left.value = in_order_successor
                    else:
                        parent_node.right.value = in_order_successor
                return True # if removed

        return False # if value doesnt exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I…make the code look better?

Follow the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).
Add [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), at least for "everything to be used externally".
Add ([doc](https://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html))tests. Or, at least, a start for tinkering:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = BinarySearchTree()
    for c in "badcef":
        t.insert(c)
    t.remove("d")
```

provide amenities like an `__str__` for node

```
    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.left is None and self.right is None

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + (self.value if self.is_leaf() else (
            (str(self.left.value + "<") if self.left else "^")
            + self.value
            + ("<" + str(self.right.value) if self.right else "^"))) + ")"
```

(It is somewhat rare that I don't provide docstrings. It felt right *here*.)

Keep classes and functions short.
 Say, 24 lines for "heads", 48 for a function body, 96 for a class.

Where not impeding readability, keep nesting level low.
 This includes *early out*s, `continue`s, `breaks` & `else` in loops; `return`s

```
    def insert(self, value):
        """ Insert value into this tree.
            ToDo: document behaviour with identical keys
                  (what about lookup()?)
        """
        latest = Node(value)
        current = self.root
        previous = None     # the parent for latest, if any
        left = None         # the child latest is going to be in parent
        while current is not None:
            previous = current
            left = value < current.value
            current = current.left if left else current.right
        if previous is None:
            self.root = latest
        elif left:
            previous.left = latest
        else:
            previous.right = latest
        return self
```

(what an awful example for changing entirely too many things at once)

Python naming style is CapWords for classes, only: that would be `new_node`.
The `left = None` statement is there for the comment.
The paranoid prefer `is None`/`is not None` over just using what *should* be a reference in a boolean context.
Above rendition tries to keep DRY and avoids some of what looks repetitious in the `insert()` you presented.
But, wait, doesn't that *descend left or right thing* look just the same in `lookup()` and `remove()`?
If I had a method

```
    def _find(self, value):
        """ Find node with value, if any.
            Return this node and setter for (re-)placing it in this tree.
        """
        pass
```

, `insert()` was simple, and `lookup()` trivial (if questionable: wording
• lookup: returns the value if it exists in the BST else returns None
, implementation returns a `Node`):

```
    def insert(self, value):
        """ Insert value into this tree.
            ToDo: document behaviour with identical keys
        """
        existing, place = self._find(value)
        if existing is not None:
            pass
        place(Node(value))
        return self
    
    def lookup(self, value):
        """ Return node with value, if any. """
        return self._find(value)[0]
```

Remove can profit from a modified *successor* method

```
    @staticmethod
    def leftmost(child, parent=None):
        """ Return the leftmost node of the tree rooted at child,
            and its parent, if any. """
        if child is not None:
            while child.left is not None:
                child, parent = child.left, child
        return child, parent
    
    def deleted(self, node):  # node None?
        """ Return root of a tree with node's value deleted. """
        successor, parent = BinarySearchTree.leftmost(node.right, node)
        if successor is None:
            return node.left
        node.value = successor.value
        if node is not parent:
            parent.left = successor.right
        else:
            node.right = successor.right
        return node
    
    def remove(self, value):
        """ Remove value.
            Return 'tree contained value'. """
        node, place = self._find(value)
        if node is None:
            return False
        place(self.deleted(node))
        return True
```

My current rendition of `_find()` adds in `Node`

```
    def _set_left(self, v):
        self.left = v
    
    def _set_right(self, v):
        self.right = v
```

, in `BinarySearchTree`

```
    def _set_root(self, v):
        self.root = v
    
    def _find(self, value):
        """ Find node with value, if any.
            Return this node and setter for (re-)placing it in this tree.
        """
        if self.root is None or self.root.value == value:
            return self.root, self._set_root
        child = self.root
        while True:
            node = child
            smaller = value < child.value
            child = child.left if smaller else child.right
            if child is None or child.value == value:
                return child, node._set_left if smaller else node._set_right
```

---

> How can I improve the speed/efficiency?

Don't spend effort there before measurements suggesting it's a bottleneck.

---

Guide-line for easy-to-use types: Don't *make* me think.

You define `inorder()` to print the values in order.
Wouldn't it be cute to be able to use, for a tree `ascending`
`for item in ascending: …`? While it was *possible* to not touch `Node`, add

```
    def __iter__(self):
        """ Yield each node in the tree rooted here in order. """
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.value
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right
```

there, and in the tree

```
    def __iter__(self):
        """ Yield each node in the tree in order. """
        if self.root is not None:
            yield from self.root
```

, enabling `print(*ascending)`

Comment: Why it felt right to omit the docstrings: you don't need a docstring for `__str__`, because everybody knows the expected behaviour; and for `is_leaf`, I think the name provides all the documentation necessary!